# NDK build for Android 11(R) not supported

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Is there anyway to build C/C++ project for android R image ?

im getting  : **"C/C++ release|x86_64 : API codeName 'R' is not supported by NDK 'D:\Android_sdk\ndk\21.1.6352462"**  error.

this is project stracture :

[image]

Im using **Android Studio 4 RC1** , **Android R Preview** and **NDK Version 21.1** for this build.

this is the gradle config :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "android-R"
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0 rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion "R"
        targetSdkVersion "R"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++17"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this comment](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/issues/702), you need to install a newer NDK from the canary channel:

> Android Studio menu,"settings > Appearance & Behavior > system Settings > Updates"
>   choose "Canary Channel"
>   The canary NDKs will be enabled for download:
>   "Tools > Sdk Manager > SDK Tools"
>   ( assuming "Show Package Details" is enabled ) "NDK side by side"

Or you can install it from the command line with

```
sdkmanager --channel=3 --install 'ndk;21.1.6363665'
```